# Neovim makes spurious directories and doesn't clean them up on exit

Tags: neovim

Neovim makes directories in my home folder (presumably to store swapfiles, etc.) of the form `nvimzOvQcg`, `nvim098eqo`, `nvimUyUGZ8`, etc.
Upon exit, the contents of these directories are cleaned up but the directories themselves are not removed.
This occurs even if I remove all of my rc files and plugins.

Has anyone experienced this before/have a solution?